# Python - Printing in line from dict

Tags: python, printing, tabs, alignment

I'm a beginner at python and I'm experiencing difficulties printing nicely.
I made a program that stores names and prices in dictionary. 
( e.g : `{"PERSON_1":"50","PERSON_2":"75","PERSON_WITH_EXTREMELY_LONG_NAME":"80"}` 
Now the problem is that I want to be able to print the keys and their supposed values in a nice scheme.
I used the code:

```
 for i in eter.eters:
        print(i + "\t | \t" + str(eter.eters[i]))
```

with eter.eters being my dictionary. 
The problem is that some names are a lot longer than others, so the tabs don't align.
As well as my header: "Names" | "Price" should be aligned with the information below.
I've already looked up some solutions, but I don't really understand the ones I found.
Desired outcome:

```
**********************************************************************
               De mensen die blijven eten zijn:
**********************************************************************
Naam                            |      bedrag
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PERSON 1                        |      50
PERSON 2                        |      75
PERSON WITH EXTREMELY LONG NAME |      80
**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Can u show the desired output for your problem.

Comment: I added it to the question! @skaul05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

given eter.eters is your dictionary

```
print('%-35s | %6s' % ('Names', 'Price')) # align to the left

for k in eter:
    print('%-35s | %6s' % (k,eter[k]))
```

or

```
print("{0:<35}".format('Name')+'|'+"{0:>6}".format('Price'))

for k in eter:
    print("{0:<35}".format(k)+'|'+"{0:>6}".format(eter.eters[k]))
```

Comment: This works better, but now it centers the names to the right, is there a way to avoid this? thanks already!

Comment: check this website for another way, a bit more complicated but it will allow you to do more formatting: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-37.php

Comment: @J Kluseczka thanks for showing how to use the '-' sign!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all of the names and find the maximum length of it. Then show every name with special padding instead of tabulator (`\t`). This code should explain:

```py
>>> d={"Marius":"50","John":"75"}
>>> d
{'Marius': '50', 'John': '75'}
>>> for i in d:
...  print(i)
... 
Marius
John
>>> d = {"Marius":"50","John":"75"}
>>> m = 0
>>> for i in d:
...  m = max(m, len(i))
... 
>>> m
6 # now we know the place reserved for Name column should be 6 chars width
>>> for i in d:
...  print( i + (m-len(i))*' ' , d[i]) # so add to the name space char that fit this 6 chars space
... 
Marius 50
John   75
```